# Javascript color generator code causing Jquery to quit

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

I have a little script that I've written to generate a random color hex code. It goes like this:

```
function genHex() {
    colors = new Array(14)
    colors[0] = '0'
    colors[1] = '1'
    colors[2] = '2'
    colors[3] = '3'
    colors[4] = '4'
    colors[5] = '5'
    colors[6] = '6'
    colors[7] = '7'
    colors[8] = '8'
    colors[9] = '9'
    colors[10] = 'a'
    colors[11] = 'b'
    colors[12] = 'c'
    colors[13] = 'd'
    colors[14] = 'e'
    colors[15] = 'f'

    digit = new Array(5)
    color = ""
    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        digit[i] = colors[Math.round(Math.random() * 14)]
        color = color + digit[i]
    }
    return color;
}
```

I know this isn't the prettiest way to accomplish what I'm doing, but the means will ultimately serve a different end for a more complex project. Regardless, when I include this `genhex.js` file alongside the latest Jquery, nothing works!

For instance,

```
$().ready(function() {
    alert(genhex());
});
```

does nothing. What am I missing here? Is there some reason that `color` not a string in this case?

Comment: What version of jquery do you use?

Comment: you could optimize your array by using `colors = [0,1,2,3,...,9,a,b,...];`

Comment: Yes, absolutely, @godesign, but this array is eventually going to be something different that will be easier to interpret with line-by-line loading of the array.

Comment: @ruzel, I've eddited your post, because you had a typo in your array declaration, don't forget to update you code too ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$(function() {
    alert(genHex());
});
```

To call `genHex()` on document ready.

Also the function is defined as `genHex()` but you're trying to call it as `genhex()`. Function names are case-sensitive in JavaScript.

Comment: That was it. Wow, I should have caught that.

Comment: Followup question: any idea why genhex() is only generating one color when called in an `each()` method? i.e. `$('h1').each(function() {
    $(this).css({color: genhex()})});`

Answer (score 0):

```
$().ready(function() {
   alert(genhex());
});
```

shoud be

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert(genHex());
});
```

Comment: Oh yeah! I'm always forgetting about jsfiddle. Thanks for the reminder.

Comment: Also, I've used `$().ready()` as well as `$(window).ready()` and `$(document).ready` and they all seem to work fine.